# How to reduce width of a form (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

I have this html page:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1>Usuarios</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios | async">
                    <td>{{usuario.nome}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.telefone}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
                    <td><button (click)="deleteUsuario(usuario.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    <button (click)="updateUsuario(usuario.id)" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px">Update</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The width is following the navbar, so it's being stretched all the screen:

[image]

How can I reduce it to the center of the screen like a have a margin before and after the form?

I want it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you actually want?

Comment: did you try margin:0 auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot I guess you are using `Materialize CSS`:

Try to the form code within below code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col s12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1>Usuarios</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios | async">
                    <td>{{usuario.nome}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.telefone}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
                    <td><button (click)="deleteUsuario(usuario.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    <button (click)="updateUsuario(usuario.id)" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 10px">Update</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this style code:

```
form {
   max-width: 900px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto
}
```

Comment: <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  style="max-width: 900px;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto" >

Comment: as i wrote, an inline style in your form tag. or if you don't like that you should create a separete .css file then link to that

Comment: if this helped you, i'll appreciate marking my answer as best answer

Comment: I edited again, i had pasted the code for the form, but the screen is actually the list of users. But tryied your answer and the form was still in the left

Comment: Oh my God! i realized the issue. put that code for parent div 
    <div class="panel panel-default"  style="max-width: 900px;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto" >